# Splits an expression into two parts if possible

Tags: pattern-matching, rule

**The series**

- The series is: $\text{expr}_{1} \pm \text{expr}_{2} ...$
- $\pm$ represents plus or minus sign.
- The number of terms in the series can be 1 or more than 1.
- Each term $\text{expr}_{n}$ is an expression, and not necessarily $ax^{n}$

**Use Case**

- I want to transform the series by:

  - Writing a rule that split the series into 1st and remaining terms.
  - Writing another rule that transform the first term.
  - Using the two rule to transform all terms of the series.

**Current Goal**

- I want to split the series into:

  - the first term, and
  - the remaining terms

**Constraint**

- I only want the pattern to match for once.

  - There are several ways to split the expression into 2 parts
  - I only want a split that keeps the first term as simple as possible.

**Test**

I will use polynomials as *test cases*.

```
rule[expr_] = expr /. {Shortest[a_] + b__ :> a}

test1 = x - 2x^{2} + 3x^{3};
rule[test1]

test2 = -x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 3x^{3};
rule[test2]

test3 = -x;
rule[test3]

test4 := -2 x^3 + Sum[Log[x], {n, 1, L}]
```

**Expected Result**

- $x$
- $-x^{4}$
- $-x$
- $-2x^3$

**Actual Result**

- $x - 2 x^2 + 3 x^3$
- $2 x^2 + 3 x^3 - x^4$
- $-x$
- $L \log (x)-2 x^3$

**Question**

The rule matches with the whole series instead of the shortest first term.

How to fix the rule?

Thanks.

Comment: I found `Part[expr, 1]` doesn't get the first term. The doc might be a lie: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PickingOutPiecesOfAlgebraicExpressions.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use braces around exponents.

Second,

```
SetAttributes[rule, HoldAll];
rule[exp_] := ({HoldForm[exp] /. Plus -> Sequence})[[1, 1]];
rule[x - 2 x^2 + 3 x^3]
rule[-x^4 + 2 x^2 + 3 x^3]
rule[-x]
(*
   x
   -x^4
   -x
*)
```

Comment: Pro: can extract each of all terms. Even works for things like: `rule[Sum[Log[x], {n, 1, L}] - 2 x^{3}]`
Con: Doesnt work if I assign the expression to a variable first. For example, `test = Sum[Log[x], {n, 1, L}] - 2 x^{3}; rule[test]` yields $\left\{-2 x^3,L \log (x)\right\}$.

Comment: Since I am using this as part of a simplification, I don't need `HoldForm`. For my case, `r1[exp_] := Part[{exp /. Plus -> Sequence}, 1];` works.

Comment: Problem: the function splits $\sum a + b$  to $\sum a$ and $b$, instead of $\sum a$ and $\sum b$.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively apply rule to each term.

```
f[exp_] := exp //. {Plus[x1_, x2__] :> f[x1] + f[x2]}
```